# How hidden form action or URL in $.post

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, post

How can I hide the addresses in the `form` (such as registration) or the information sent by AJAX or its link?

Is there a way to secure the messaging with AJAX to make the post and the destination address unrecognizable?

Deactivating the right-click with various plugins will see codes and especially the addresses of the secret pages, which are not reliable. I am grateful that somebody will detail a professional way

Comment: This is not possible. Any information sent in a request, and the URL the data is sent to, is publically available. It has to be by definition. If you're concerned about security you need to look at server side solutions to ensure that any data that's received meets business logic requirements. Any time spent trying to do this client-side is time completely wasted.

Comment: Security like this on the client side is useless. Just lock down the endpoint and sanitize/validate your inputs on the server side and you'll be fine. Don't fall for the trap of [Security through Obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).